# Constrain loss function based on input variables

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions, constraint

I'm doing a simple regression task using a neural network with two inputs (`x1` and `x2`) and one output (`y`). I want to add an additional term to my loss function such that when `x1=0` we always get `y=x2`.

How would I formulate an additional term to account for this?

Comment: Wait, are you trying to manually correct the loss function in certain cases or are you trying to make the model forecast a specific value in this certain case?

Comment: You don’t even need to change the neural network. Just put an if/then statement in your code.